# Some question of "Cloud endpoint creation failed"

Tags: azure, authorization

I want to add cloud endpoints in the Azure Sync group, my role is a contributor to EA.

There has an error message

> "cloud endpoint creation failed" when I add the cloud endpoint in Azure Sync group.

Cloud endpoint '*****'

> Code: 'AuthorizationFailed'

Details:

> The client '**' with object id '***' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/**/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/***storage/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/****'.

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly indicates that your role does not have permissions for role assignments. A `Contributor` role has all the permissions of that of an `Owner` role except assigning roles permission.

To solve this problem, you can:

- Either make yourself an `Owner` on the subscription or at the resource level (storage account in your case).
- Create a custom role using `Contributor` role as a template and add `RoleAssignment` capability to that role. You can then ask an owner to assign you that role.

Comment: which is being governed by the `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` action

Answer (score 1):

Another reply is correct basically, but one point is not correct, except assigning roles permission, the `Contributor` role also have other actions which it is not able to perform, like **Delete roles and role assignments**, **Create or update any blueprint artifacts**, **Delete any blueprint artifacts**.

For more details, you could refer to **NotActions** in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor).

[image]

To fix the issue, as mentioned,

- Just perform the action with an `Owner` role at the scope of the subscription or storage account.
- Assign you a custom role with the permission of `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write`, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) for more details about custom roles.

Comment: @Arthur If it is helpful, you could accept it as the answer.